# Understanding the behavior of increase in class count or classes loaded

Tags: java

I am using a custom class loader `CustomClassLoader` to create an instance of a class `DemoClass`.
When monitoring the verbose output of the vm, I notice

```
[Loaded packageName.DemoClass from file:workspace/bin/]
```

On jconsole window, I notice the classes loaded count increasing in proportion to the instances created.

Any pointers to understand this behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by classes loaded count increasing? What is the issue here? Class should be loaded only once.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit broad.

Without further context I would have to conclude that you are not reusing the `ClassLoader` but creating a new one each time you instantiate your class.

Now that could be correct and legitimate behaviour depending on what you are trying to do, e.g. if you are trying to implement a dynamic language type feature you may actually want a different class each time, but an easier way to achieve that is to just generate new class names and use the existing classloader (unless you will be able to unload the instances as they expire and want to have each classloader cleaner for unloading)